# regexp_substring cannot be cast to scala.Function2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```sql
case when lower(description) like '%route of administration%' then text_answer
     when mnemonic is not null then regexp_substr(lower(mnemonic),'(oral|topical|otic|rectal|nasal|vaginal|(inhalat|intra|subcut|transd|ophth)[a-z]+)')
     else null 
end as localroute
```

while executing the above am getting error as

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
> com.optum.cdr.fe.utils.UDFs.regexp_substring$$anonfun$1 cannot be cast
> to scala.Function2

Comment: It seems the error comes from your UDF `regexp_substring`. How is this function defined? why not use Spark builtin `regexp_extract`?

Comment: I tried using regexp_extract and after using that am getting an error as scala.StringContext$InvalidEscapeException: invalid escape character at index case when lower(descrip) like '%dis qtyunit%' then col1
     when col2 is not null then trim(regexp_extract(lower(col2), '((caps|tab|powd|syr|aero|liq|susp)[a-z]|solution|lotion|spray|([^a-z0-9])?extended release|\s)+'))
     else null end as Column